# Sharing scope in different views with custom controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got the next problem and I'd like to find a solution or if I should even be doing this like I am.

I have the following ui-router configuration:

```
$stateProvider.state('ListCounterparties', {
    url:"/counterparties",
    data: { NavMenuItem : 'Counterparties / Desks' },
    views: {
        '' : {
            templateUrl:"./app/module_Counterparties/templates/ListCounterparties.html",
            controller:"CounterpartiesControllerCtrl"
        },
        'deskLists@ListCounterparties' : {
            templateUrl : './app/module_Counterparties/templates/DesksDualListTemplate.html',
            controller:'DesksControllerCtrl'
        }
}
```

The first, unnamed view, has a table from which I can select a row and then a method will be called to populate a dual list from the second view.

Up until now, I've had both in the same controller, but the controller is getting too big and I decided I had to separate them.

The method to populate the dual lists in '**deskLists@ListCounterparties**' is defined in **DesksControllerCtrl** but it should be called in **CounterpartiesControllerCtrl**, as the event of row selection is in that controller.

The problem is that the scopes are not shared and the method is inaccesible to the unnamed view.

Accessing the scope in **DesksControllerCtrl** I could see that accessing the $parent property twice I can get to the **CounterpartiesControllerCtrl**, but I don't thin that's an ideal thing to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to share a real `scope` or just data?

Comment: Probably the scope as I'll be calling methods from one controller from the other.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing data, methods, etc. between multiple controllers the *Angular way* would be to create **service(s)**. That means, you create e.g. a **service** which holds all your data and another one which provides functionality for several controllers. Then, just `inject` them in your controllers:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('myGlobalData', function() {
  return {
    data: 1
  };
});

myApp.factory('myService', function(myGlobalData) {
  return {
    increment: function() {
      myGlobalData.data++;
    }
  };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrlA', function($scope, myGlobalData, myService) {
  $scope.myGlobalData = myGlobalData;
  $scope.myService = myService;
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrlB', function($scope, myGlobalData, myService) {
  $scope.myGlobalData = myGlobalData;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <p ng-controller="MyCtrlA">
    {{myGlobalData.data}}
  </p>

  <p ng-controller="MyCtrlB">
    {{myGlobalData.data}}
  </p>

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrlA">
    <button ng-click="myService.increment()">Increment data in myGlobalData service</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's a pretty simple and nice solution, as an only caveat I see that you have to inject two services to get the functionality working.

That in big applications can get a bit messy, I've actually found a good scalable solution from one of the posts here at stack overflow, I'll post it later when I've got some more time.

But you gave me the idea of actually sharing the data in a way other than inheriting scopes.

Comment: Well, I have injected the same `myService` in two different *controllers*. Sharing functionality globally by means of *services*, *filters*,  etc is a basic idea of AngularJS.

Comment: If you don't inject the services, and using scope inheritance (invisible) I think than it will go messy in big applications... as you don't know what can access what.